# Insert square brackets around some text in a cell using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to insert square brackets around some text in a cell with Excel VBA code, where there is none?

It needs to find the text before the first comma and if there are no square brackets before the first comma, wrap it with [ ] square brackets

The text in cell A is in this format. It is all in one single text string

```
A12345, blah, blah, blah, blah blah
[B45678], blah, blah, blah, blah blah
C97665, blah, blah, blah, blah blah
D89798, blah, blah, blah, blah blah
[B97494], blah, blah, blah, blah blah
Y34987, blah, blah, blah, blah blah
```

I need to run it into

```
[A12345], blah, blah, blah, blah blah
[B45678], blah, blah, blah, blah blah
[C97665], blah, blah, blah, blah blah
[D89798], blah, blah, blah, blah blah
[B97494], blah, blah, blah, blah blah
[Y34987], blah, blah, blah, blah blah
```

I have no VBA knowledge but thought it would be best handled using VBA as there could be thousands of rows

Comment: It is definitely possible... I'd say have a look at the `InStr` function http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-instr-function/ looking for the first comma and then lookin at the first letter of the string.... Give it a try and, if you get stuck, post up some code as a new question with a specific issue you're trying to overcome.

Comment: Quite honestly, you could even manage it with an excel formula just as easily.

Comment: I would use blank space as a delimiter, then add columns between the new values and put in the "[" and "]" around the text, then concatenate the values together.

Comment: The closest formula I can work out is: =IF(ISERROR(MID($A2,FIND("[",$A2)*1,FIND("]",$A2)-FIND("[",$A2)+1)),"["&LEFT(A2,6)&"]",IF(ISERROR(LEFT($A2,FIND("@@@",SUBSTITUTE($A2,",","@@@",1))-1)),"NO CODE",LEFT($A2,FIND("@@@",SUBSTITUTE($A2,",","@@@",1))-1))). However it doesn't exclude text that doesn't have a comma as it still wraps brackets around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

Running this small macro:

```
Sub bracket()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long, s As String
    Dim i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        ary = Split(Cells(i, 1).Text, ",")
        If Left(ary(0), 1) = "[" Then
        Else
            ary(0) = "[" & ary(0) & "]"
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Join(ary, ",")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To adapt the original code to work with data in column **E** we need to change *3* lines of code:

```
Sub bracket()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long, s As String
    Dim i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        ary = Split(Cells(i, 5).Text, ",")
        If Left(ary(0), 1) = "[" Then
        Else
            ary(0) = "[" & ary(0) & "]"
            Cells(i, 5).Value = Join(ary, ",")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

this is because `Cells(13,1)` refers to cell **A13**, and `Cells(13,5)` would refer to cell **E13**.

Comment: This works much better as it resolves the problem in situ, rather than having to create another column. Thank you

Comment: I tried to get this to work in column E, so change "A" to N = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row, but it still changes text in column A

Comment: @BradleyS  See my **EDIT#1**